# Setting up a RESTful service for Backbone.js with apache and windows

Tags: php, apache, rest, backbone.js, slim

I'm trying to set up a RESTful web service on my apache localhost to serve as the back-end for my backbone app. I have tried:

1. Setting up WebDAV, but get the following error messages in the logs

   [Thu Feb 23 21:46:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Unable to PUT new contents for /clusters/19.  [403, #0], referer: http://ideas.localhost/
   [Thu Feb 23 21:46:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] An error occurred while opening a resource.  [500, #0], referer: http://ideas.localhost/
2. Using Backbone.emulateHTTP, which causes a `405 method not allowed error` (something I guess is caused by the `X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT` header as normal POST requests are working fine

I'm running Apache 2.2.21 and PHP 5.3 on windows 7, and below is my .htaccess file. I'm also using the SLIM framework to handle url routing.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

And virtual host config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "G:/sites/ideas"
    Dav On // I also had security setting set to Allow all as it's just my localhost
    ServerName ideas.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/ideas.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/ideas.localhost-access.log" combined
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
</VirtualHost>
```

I've been struggling to get something to work for ages, so any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you making a subdomain on localhost?

Comment: Yes, config pasted above

Comment: Also, and update - I got so bogged down with server config using web dav that when I turned on Backbone.emulateHTTP I neglected to do any proper debugging of PHP. It turns out that SLIM is getting the request and then throwing the 405 error, so maybe I just need to configure the app to look for the headers.

Comment: I think the subdomain won't work properly, as ideas.localhost, unless you edit also the host file - `127.0.0.1 ideas.localhost`

Comment: But there is one new oddity - two `PUT` requests are sent by different model types to differnt urls, but the `Allow` response header is didfferent for both responses. One is set to `GET HEAD`, the other to `PUT DELETE`, and theres' no reason why there shodul be any difference as far as I can see.

Comment: @Bakudan already done and the virtual host is working perfectly for GET and POST

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't believe I solved the problem less than an hour after opening a bounty, but hey ho.

The problem was that Slim doesn't have a built in ability to handle the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header used by backbone and the error message isn't very descriptive. Adding the following at the bottom of request.php and using emulateHTTP mode in Backbone fixed it

```
protected function checkForHttpMethodOverride() {
    if ( isset($this->post[self::METHOD_OVERRIDE]) ) {
        $this->method = $this->post[self::METHOD_OVERRIDE];
        unset($this->post[self::METHOD_OVERRIDE]);
        if ( $this->isPut() ) {
            $this->put = $this->post;
        }
    } else if(isset($this->headers['x-method-override'] )) {
        $this->method = $this->headers['x-method-override'];
        if ( $this->isPut() ) {
            $this->put = $this->post;
        }
    }
}
```

PS - I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/pull/252) for SLIM to include this by default, so if you think it'd be a good idea to include this in the framework please leave a comment there