# 405 Error From Slim PHP while using Backbone JS with MAMP

Tags: php, javascript, rest, backbone.js, slim

I'm new to backbonejs and slim but I'm diving right in.

my backbone code is fine, and it works when I use localstorage, but I want to use a mysql back end. I did some homework and found the SLIM framework. Looked pretty cool, RESTful, etc. I've seen that its been used a bunch with backbone.

backbone gets information from the file fine.

When backbone requests my file with the PUT, I get: POST http://localhost:8888/lifeconsole/src/server/ 405 (Method Not Allowed).

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422210/setting-up-a-restful-service-for-backbone-js-with-apache-and-windows)

I replaced the suggested section of SLIM code in the answers section.

I also modified my httpd.conf file to allow .htaccess files in local directories. I ensured that I had the .htaccess file that ships with SLIM in the directory with my SLIM files. I've been doing a lot of reading about apache configuration and feel a little over my head. Any suggestions would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I was confused about a basic feature of REST. The PUT method is only used upon update. I had written code for GET and PUT and I should have had something for POST. That being said, I'm pretty sure PUT doesn't work on many servers, and you need to flip on http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync-emulateHTTP to make backbone work.